# What does the halal certification of drinks (e.g. coffee) mean?

Tags: food, halal-certification

The meaning of halal as per google is

> adjective: halal
>
> 1.
>   denoting or relating to meat prepared as prescribed by Muslim law.
>   "halal butchers"
>   religiously acceptable according to Muslim law.
>   "halal banking"
>
> noun: halal
>   1.
>   halal meat.

Today there was a news article saying a certain coffee is now halal certified; [NT News](http://www.ntnews.com.au/business/halal-move-sparks-pauls-iced-coffee-boycott/story-fnk2tq5v-1227121815179) writes:

> TERRITORIANS opposed to halal certification are boycotting Paul's Iced Coffee, flooding social media with their protests.
>
> The iconic Territory drink has been the target of online hate because it is halal certified.

How can liquid/milk be certified as halal? There is no meat in milk or coffee, then what does halal certification mean?

Comment: Despite the title, this is almost definitely due to the fact that it's a dairy product rather than a coffee product.  As such, it's probably a duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18477/22